# treeview with Checkbox

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, treeview, checkbox

I need to show a treeview with checkboxes to select in MVC with C#.

I have two tables. one with categories and subcategories and the other one with products. Some categories wont have sub categories in the first table, they'll have only products.

I need to populate the Treeview with these two tables. Please suggest me to do it in MVC and also using jquery by which the page wont get refresh on selecting the parent nodes

Comment: possible duplicate of [JQuery Checkbox Treeview](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1538738/jquery-checkbox-treeview)

Answer (score 1):

jQGrid will show both [Trees](http://www.trirand.com/jqgrid/jqgrid.html) and [Nested](http://www.trirand.com/jqgrid/jqgrid.html) grids (any and all with Checkboxes). They have an example of binding with a JSON source, so you would make a controller method for your data source that uses the [JSONResult](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.jsonresult.aspx) ActionResult type method to serialize in a JSON object your records to show in the grids.

Comment: links are unavailable!