# JQuery Checkbox Treeview

Tags: jquery-plugins, treeview, jquery

I am looking for a JQuery Checkbox Treeview. Does anyone know if a good one exists?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

The best treeview I've found for jQuery so far is Dynatree. Very comprehensive, and with great documentation.

> [Dynatree is now hosted on **Google Code**](http://code.google.com/p/dynatree/)

original answer link [is here](http://wwwendt.de/tech/dynatree/).

Comment: Great tree! And regular updated! http://code.google.com/p/dynatree/downloads/list

Comment: This has been replaced with FancyTree https://github.com/mar10/fancytree

Answer (score 10):

This one seems good and up to date:
http://code.google.com/p/checkboxtree/

Comment: As far as checkboxes: looks very fast and efficient. Might be on par with Dynatree, however the latter looks better overall.

Answer (score 5):

jsTree appears to be a pretty good solution, too:  [www.jstree.com](http://www.jstree.com)

Answer (score 3):

It depends on if you need partial checking(if less than max of the child are checked, the parent is in a different state)

If you need that case, this one should be better: 
http://code.google.com/p/jquery-checktree/downloads/list