# Free javascript tree view library with checkbox/multiselect

Tags: javascript

I want to find a javascript library that supports folder-like tree view with checkbox/ multiselect. There are quite a number of libraries, such as www.treeview.net, but lots of them requires purchase or including advertising link.

Can I find any free javascript library that support tree view with checkbox?

Comment: possible duplicate of [JQuery Checkbox Treeview](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1538738/jquery-checkbox-treeview)

Comment: I am the author of the old project https://code.google.com/p/zkjs/ I have clean the code and create document for the tree component and move it to github. https://imhazige.github.io/kee-tree/

Answer (score 3):

try this one

http://kazge.com/show/zkjs/src/tree.html

it support checkbox, and more feature

the project's home page is https://code.google.com/p/zkjs/

Comment: very cool indeed :) I wish I have known about it before :)

Answer (score 1):

I've used http://sortablejs.github.io/Sortable/#nested with great success. The default UI might throw you off (it doesn't look like a tree) but when you consider mobile users this look actually works much better.

I've never tried using checkboxes with it but I doubt it would be a problem.